# How to export DLL or LIB to MinGW .a file for correct link

Tags: c++, c, dll, mingw, lib

I want to use .a file export from DLL to link the C++ program, the full archive that I got was: a header, a DLL file and a LIB which built by VC++.
now I use pexports and dlltool to export DLL functions into .a library:

```
pexports some.dll -o > some.def
dlltool --dllname some.dll --def some.def --output-lib some.a
```

when I linking with some.a I got errors from compiler:

```
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `some_function@8'
```

so I view some.def file it defines like below:

```
LIBRARY "some.dll"
EXPORTS
some_function  @1
some_function2 @2
```

and then I decide to switch to another way to export .a file from .LIB file which built by VC++:

```
reimp some.lib
dlltool -d some.def -l libsome.a
```

and then I got link correctly using libsome.a because some.def defines like:

```
LIBRARY "some.dll"
EXPORTS
some_function  @8  --> ( param size? )
some_function2 @24
```

but when I running the program I got runtime error:
can not find the entry address "some_function@8" at some.dll ...

why the result of export .a from DLL file and from LIB file was different ? how do I solve the problem ? thank you.

Comment: Have you tried linking with the provided LIB file?

Comment: yes, but can't link.

Comment: Any updates on this? I seem to find little information about how to do this but ran into needing exactly the same thing...

Comment: @AcidTonic the problem past very long time, as in my memory the solve is using dynamic DLL call. for example: func = GetFunction(DLL_handle, "@xxx_func");